# Swipe between fragments with help of BottomNavigationBar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I have trouble finding a good example on how to swipe between `fragments` with help of `bottom navigatiom bar`. Since [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter) is deprecated and a new [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) is now recommended instead of the old ViewPager I want to use [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) and [FragmentStateAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter) in my code instead. I have found an example of how to combine BottomNavigationBar and ViewPager [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128491/how-to-combine-bottomnavigationview-and-viewpager) and I want to do something similar. My code have many similarities to the one in the example with the only difference that I have my code in a fragment instead of an activity. [Here is a picture of how my FrontendFragment display look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSKUd.png). I can switch between the views using the bottomnavigationbar but I also want to be able to swipe between the views. Can someone help me or at least direct me on the right way? Here is my code:

**FragmentPagerAdapter Class:**

```
public class FragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private static final int mFragmentCount = 5;

    public FragmentPagerAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position){

            case 0:
                return new HomeFragment();
            case 1:
                return new SearchFragment();
            case 2:
                return new AddFragment();
            case 3:
                return new MessageFragment();
            case 4:
                return new ProfileFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFragmentCount;
    }
}
```

**FrontendFragment Class:**

```
public class FrontendFragment extends Fragment implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView;
    private ViewPager2 mViewPager2;
    private FragmentPagerAdapter mFragmentPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frontend, container, false);

        loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

        mBottomNavigationView = v.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationBar);
        mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        Fragment selectedFragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home_icon:
                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.search_icon:
                selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.add_icon:
                selectedFragment = new AddFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.message_icon:
                selectedFragment = new MessageFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.profile_icon:
                selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
        }
        
        return loadFragment(selectedFragment);
    }


    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment selectedFragment) {

        if(selectedFragment != null){

            MainActivity.sFm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relLayoutMiddle, selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm already using BottomNav with ViewPager2 in one of my app, I can help.

Your code is partially correct which means your `FragmentPagerAdapter`  is fine, but not your `FrontEndFragment`.

See, the `FragmentPagerAdapter` has to be set to a `ViewPager2` as

```
//this here is the FrontEndFragment 
mViewPager2.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(this));
```

Then, You don't have to do the FragmentTransaction at all, you just have to change the `ViewPager2`'s current item position through the `BottomNavigationBar` as

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home_icon:
            mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(0);
            break;
        case R.id.search_icon:
            mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(1);
            break;
        case R.id.add_icon:
            mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(2);
            break;

        case R.id.message_icon:
            mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(3);
            break;

        case R.id.profile_icon:
            mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(4);
            break;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

This is all, you don't have to deal with `Fragments` at all apart from the `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Also, don't forget to remove the `loadFragment(new HomeFragment());` which is not required, nor the function `loadFragment()` is required.

(Optional), Furthermore, if you want to disable the Swipe Action of the `ViewPager2` and want the Fragments to be selected based on the Selected BottomNav item only, then you can set `setUserInputEnabled()` property of `ViewPager2` as `false`.

---

Next, to set the `BottomNavigationBar`'s item as selected based on the swipe of the `ViewPager2`, what you've to do is,

Create a global var

```
MenuItem previousMenuItem;
```

Then, set a default item (first) to be selected of BottomNav on activity start as

```
mBottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

Finally, set an `OnPageSelected()` callback on `ViewPager2` to update the selected Menu Item as:

```
mViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        super.onPageSelected(position);
        if (previousMenuItem != null) {
            previousMenuItem.setChecked(false);
        }
        else {
            mBottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
        }
        mBottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
        previousMenuItem = mBottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
    }
});
```

What you're doing here is that you're setting default item to `previousMenuItem` and then on swiping to a different page, deselecting the `previousMenuItem` and selecting the new one, which means updating the BottomNav based on ViewPager's current item. This is the complete code you require to acheive your objective.

Comment: Thanks! I just implemented your code, howver I am getting an error at `mViewPager2.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter());` since I need to pass a fragment in `FragmentPagerAdapter`. What do I pass there? Also I do need to find viewpager2 id before setting the adapter right? just to be sure as I am new to coding. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @MohammedAbdu Yes, you've to initialize the `mViewPager2` as `mViewPager2 = v.findViewById(R.id.yourViewPagerID);`, then you've to set the adapter of it. And, in the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, you've to pass the `Fragment` as `mViewPager2.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(this));`. It will work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been stuggling the whole day to findout how to do and now you have saved me! :) It totally works!

Comment: Just one last thing, as I am trying to learn everything so I do not have to struggle more. Why do I pass in `this` as fragment? what does `this` stand for in this context? Sorry for any inconvinence.

Comment: @MohammedAbdu `this` always depends on the scope from where you're sending it. Now, you might have noticed that `FragmentStateAdapter`'s Constructor needs a Fragment as defined in your code here `public FragmentPagerAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {`. It needs the `FrontEndFragment` and when you pass `this`, you actually pass the running instance of `FrontEndFragment` from itself as `this`. As you're in the overridden function `onCreateView()` and not in context of another class like any callback, it works. Else, you'd have to specify which this as `this@FrontEndFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swipe between views, a simple solution would be to store all views in your parent view, but set all layouts for views except the initial view to `android:visibility="gone"`. Make sure to set the initial view layout to `android:visibility="visible"` though. Now on you button clicks, you will have to implement onClick such that they turn on/ off view visibilities accordingly. For example, store views in order and control them via array index. But the whole thing you're trying to do is generally not a good design pattern *in my opinion*.

Why don't you load another Activity onClick instead of crowding your single activity? This will cause load time issues. Even if the views are non-visible, it's just an overall hassle to maintain all that in one place.